# Run fastapi app in a dockerized container on Azure functions

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, fastapi

I am trying to run a fastapi application using a docker container on Azure functions. It is giving a 404 when I try to hit the endpoint, I have made the required changes to host.json and function.json
Given below is what my function **init** file looks like and the folder structure

```
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import fastapi
import azure.functions as func
import nest_asyncio
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
nest_asyncio.apply()

app=fastapi.FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
@app.get("hello/{name}")
async def get_name(
  name: str,):
  return {
      "name": name,}

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3qlH.png)

Comment: check the stream log if the container pulled the image and if there's no errors

Comment: Yes, in the logs I can see that the container pulled the image and there were no errors. Whenever I try to hit the endpoint I get this
2022-08-31T14:19:29.806349999Z: [INFO]        Executed 'Functions.dockertest' (Succeeded, Id=8b8b2d6f-fa34-48b0-8f81-3df188e6278b, Duration=12ms)

Comment: there should not be any errors to pull the image, but to run it